# Bootstrap confidence interval for time series

Tags: python, confidence-interval, bootstrap

I have the following time series of a quantity Y (blue dots) and a function fitted on those data points (red line):

[image: time series of quantity Y]

The distribution of the quantity Y can be seen in the second plot:

[image: distribution of Y]

I am trying to calculate the confidence intervals for the fitted function. I thought I could use Bootstrap for that but due to the time dependency I think I do not satisfy the iid (independent and identically distributed) condition. Can I then use only Block-Bootstrap starting from a range of ~1700s or is there any other way to get the confidence intervals?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there a model behind this line? How did you fit this line?

Comment: I use a combination of lmfit's exponential model `lmfit.models.ExponentialModel()` and linear model `lmfit.models.LinearModel()`. I then use `mod.fit(y, params, x=x)` to fit my data and plot it afterwards by evaluating my model with `mod.eval(x=y, ...)`.